# My programming language's parser wont check anything after the first block or first statement and while loops will only take in one statement

Tags: java, parsing, programming-languages

I made a programming language in Java. However, I am having some issues with my parser. The parser only checks the first block or statement or it just checks the first statement, and then it stops checking the rest of what has been inputted. I am not quite sure why it is doing this. It is not meant to happen that way.

A similar thing also happens for while statements in my programming language. While statements are only taking in one statement and then no more, and if one or more is given my language will print out an error (not a Java error but just a print statement that is used as error-handling for my programming language that I have made). I have tried using `do { statement(); }while(accept("SEMICOLON"));` and while loops but that doesn't seem to work. I also tried something similar to that for the first issue as well but to no avail.

My goal is to get the parser to check more than just one block or statement, and to make the while loops take in more than one statement, like how it should be working according to my language's grammar. Hopefully one of you can help me with these problems.

Tokenizer:

```java
package dev.fransk.tundra;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Tokenizer {

    // Read file
    public static void readFile() {
        try {
            File myObj = new File("filename.txt");
            Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
            while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                String data = myReader.nextLine();
                System.out.println(data);
            }
            myReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Tokens
    public static enum Token {
        STR("\"([^\"]*)\""), IGNORE("~([^~]*)~"), EXTERN("extern"), 
    FLOAT("float"), SCAN("scan"), STRING("string"),
        VOID("void"), WHILE("while"), WRITELN("writeln"), WORD("[a-zA-Z_]+"), 
    FLT("-?[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+"), LTEQ("<="),
        GTEQ(">="), LT("<"), GT(">"), DEQ("=="), NTEQ("!="), MUL("\\*"), 
    DIV("/"), PLUS("\\+"), MINUS("\\-"),
        MODULO("%"), EQ("="), SEMICOLON(";"), LCUR("\\{"), RCUR("\\}"), SKIP("[ 
    \t\f\r\n]+"), ERROR(".");

        public final String pattern;

        Token(String pattern) {
            this.pattern = pattern;
        }
    }

    public static class Word {
        public Token token;
        public String lexeme;

        public Word(Token token, String lexeme) {
            this.token = token;
            this.lexeme = lexeme;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            if (token.name() == "SKIP")
                return "";

            return String.format("%-10s: [%s]", token.name(), lexeme);
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<Word> lex(String input) {
        ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();

        StringBuffer tokenPatternsBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (Token token : Token.values())
            tokenPatternsBuffer.append(String.format("|(?<%s>%s)", token.name(), 
    token.pattern));
        Pattern tokenPatterns = Pattern.compile(new 
    String(tokenPatternsBuffer.substring(1)));

        Matcher matcher = tokenPatterns.matcher(input);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            for (Token token : Token.values())
                if (matcher.group(token.name()) != null) {
                    words.add(new Word(token, matcher.group(token.name())));
                    continue;
                }
        }
        return words;
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> tokenList = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> lexemeList = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Here is the Parser class:

```java
package dev.fransk.tundra;

public class Parser {
    
    public static int i;
    private static Tokenizer tokenizer;
    
    public static boolean accept(String s) {
        if(tokenizer.tokenList.get(i).equals(s)) {
            i++;
            return true;
        }else if(tokenizer.tokenList.get(i).equals("EOF")) {
            for(;;)
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean expect(String s) {
        if(accept(s))
            return true;
        System.out.println("Parsing error. Expect: unexpected symbol");
        return false;
    }
    
    public static void factor() {
        if(accept("FLT"))
            ;
        else if(accept("STR"))
            ;
        else if(accept("WORD"))
            ;
        else
            System.out.println("Parsing error. Factor: syntax error");
    }
    
    public static void term() {
        factor();
        while(tokenizer.tokenList.get(i).equals("PLUS") || 
    tokenizer.tokenList.get(i).equals("MINUS")
                || tokenizer.tokenList.get(i).equals("MUL") || 
    tokenizer.tokenList.get(i).equals("DIV")
                || tokenizer.tokenList.get(i).equals("MODULO")) {
            i++;
            factor();
        }
    }
    
    public static void condition() {
        term();
        if(tokenizer.tokenList.get(i).equals("LT") || 
    tokenizer.tokenList.get(i).equals("GT") || 
                tokenizer.tokenList.get(i).equals("LTEQ") || 
    tokenizer.tokenList.get(i).equals("GTEQ") || 
                tokenizer.tokenList.get(i).equals("DEQ") || 
    tokenizer.tokenList.get(i).equals("NTEQ")) {
            i++;
            term();
        }else
            System.out.println("Parsing error. Condition: invalid operator");
    }
    
    public static void statement() {
        if(accept("WORD")) {
            expect("EQ");
            term();
            expect("SEMICOLON");
        }else if(accept("EXTERN")) {
            expect("IGNORE");
            expect("SEMICOLON");
        }else if(accept("WRITELN")) {
            term();
            expect("SEMICOLON");
        }else if(accept("WHILE")) { // Second issue around here
            condition();
            expect("LCUR");
            do {
                statement();
            }while(accept("SEMICOLON"));
            expect("RCUR");
        }else
            System.out.println("Parsing error. Statement: syntax error");
    }
    
    public static void block() {
        if(accept("FLOAT")) {
            expect("WORD");
            expect("SEMICOLON");
        }
        if(accept("STRING")) {
            expect("WORD");
            expect("SEMICOLON");
        }
        statement();
    }
    
    public static void program() {
        block(); // First issue around here
    }
}
```

Class that includes Main function:

```java
package dev.fransk.tundra;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import dev.fransk.tundra.Tokenizer.Word;

public class Tundra {
    
    private static Tokenizer tokenizer;
    private static Parser parser;
    //private static Translator translator;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "float a; a = 3.0; string b; b = \"a\"; extern 
     ~System.out.println(\"e\");~;";
        
        ArrayList<Word> words = tokenizer.lex(input);
        
        for (Word word : words) {
            if(word.token.name() == "ERROR")
                throw new java.lang.Error("Lexing Error: The token \'" + 
    word.lexeme + "\' is invalid");
            
            if(word.token.name() != "SKIP") {
                tokenizer.tokenList.add(String.valueOf(word.token));
                tokenizer.lexemeList.add(String.valueOf(word.lexeme));
            }
        }
        tokenizer.tokenList.add("EOF");
        tokenizer.lexemeList.add("EOF");
        
        System.out.println(tokenizer.tokenList + "\n" + tokenizer.lexemeList);
        parser.program();
    }
}
```

If you need anymore code it can be found here: https://github.com/Fransk7/tundra

Comment: Don't post links to or images of code.  And don't do a code dump here.  Just post a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @WJS Thank you for your feedback. I have edited my question to now include the code for the Parser class.

Comment: Please read the requirements of an `mre`.  This does not compile.  Please also note that SO is not a debugging service.  Folks here can help with syntax or how to use certain API features or in some cases help with very small programs or executable snippets of code.   As far as parsing goes have you considered using ANTLR or some other Java compatible parser generator.

Comment: @WJS I have added the code that is needed, the tokenizer and the main file. Sorry about that. Also, I did think about using ANTLR but the purpose of what I was trying to do was to learn how to make a language, not how to use a library. I wanted to figure out how the entire process works and I feel by using a library I wouldn't be learning as much as I would wish. I feel like using a library would take away from the learning experience.

Comment: Perhaps I'm overlooking something, but where in your code for `block` do you attempt to parse more than one statement? At a casual glance, it seems to just call `statement` exactly once and then return. Why do you expect a different behaviour?

Comment: @rici If you could tell me how to get it to be called more than once that would be great. I think that would solve my issues that I am having. I am not sure how to do it though, I tried `while` and `do-while` loops but I end up with Java errors when I try those.

Comment: If your issue is that statement is only being called once ("it only parses one statement") then the solution, logically, is to call it more than once, presumably in a loop. There are certainly loops elsewhere in your code, which suggests that either you know how to write a loop, but perhaps all that fine code is copied from elsewhere. Anyway, I cannot help you figure out why you got Java errors if you don't say (1) what the errors were,, exactly, and (2) what the erroneous program text was. Perhaps you need to ask some question more targetted at your level of understanding of Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question by slightly changing the grammar. Periods now separate statements/blocks, and same for in while loops.

```java
package dev.fransk.tundra;

public class Parser {
    
    public static int i;
    
    // Functions
    public static boolean accept(String s) {
        if(Tokenizer.tokenList.get(i).equals(s)) {
            i++;
            return true;
        }else if(Tokenizer.tokenList.get(i).equals("EOF")) {
            for(;;)
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean expect(String s) {
        if(accept(s))
            return true;
        System.out.println("Parsing error. Expect: unexpected symbol at " + i);
        return false;
    }
    
    public static void factor() {
        if(accept("FLT"))
            ;
        else if(accept("STR"))
            ;
        else if(accept("WORD"))
            ;
        else
            System.out.println("Parsing error. Factor: syntax error at " + i);
    }
    
    public static void term() {
        factor();
        while(Tokenizer.tokenList.get(i).equals("PLUS") || Tokenizer.tokenList.get(i).equals("MINUS")
                || Tokenizer.tokenList.get(i).equals("MUL") || Tokenizer.tokenList.get(i).equals("DIV")
                || Tokenizer.tokenList.get(i).equals("MODULO")) {
            i++;
            factor();
        }
    }
    
    public static void condition() {
        term();
        if(Tokenizer.tokenList.get(i).equals("LT") || Tokenizer.tokenList.get(i).equals("GT") || 
                Tokenizer.tokenList.get(i).equals("LTEQ") || Tokenizer.tokenList.get(i).equals("GTEQ") || 
                Tokenizer.tokenList.get(i).equals("DEQ") || Tokenizer.tokenList.get(i).equals("NTEQ")) {
            i++;
            term();
        }else
            System.out.println("Parsing error. Condition: invalid operator at " + i);
    }
    
    public static void statement() {
        if(accept("WORD")) {
            expect("EQ");
            term();
            expect("SEMICOLON");
        }else if(accept("EXTERN")) {
            expect("IGNORE");
            expect("SEMICOLON");
        }else if(accept("WRITELN")) {
            term();
            expect("SEMICOLON");
        }else if(accept("WHILE")) {
            condition();
            expect("LCUR");
            statement();
            while(Tokenizer.tokenList.get(i).equals("PERIOD")) {
                i++;
                statement();
            }
            expect("RCUR");
        }else
            System.out.println("Parsing error. Statement: syntax error at " + i);
    }
    
    public static void block() {
        if(accept("FLOAT")) {
            expect("WORD");
            expect("SEMICOLON");
        }
        if(accept("STRING")) {
            expect("WORD");
            expect("SEMICOLON");
        }
        statement();
    }
    
    public static void program() {
        block(); 
        while(Tokenizer.tokenList.get(i).equals("PERIOD")) {
            i++;
            block();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've looked over your code and noticed some strange constructs.

Why do you do this (which generates inefficient code) and imo is difficult to read.  You want to only print the error if none of the `accept` calls returns true.  Note:  the compiler actually generates what I call `leap-frog` code where it branches around `goto` bytecode.

```
public static void factor() {
     if(accept("FLT"))
         ;
     else if(accept("STR"))
         ;
     else if(accept("WORD"))
         ;
     else
         System.out.println("Parsing error. Factor: syntax error");
 }
```

Instead of this.  If any accept call returns `true`, the result will be `true` so  `!true` is `false` and the print will never occur unless they are all `false`.

```
public static void factor1() {
        if (!(accept("FLT") || accept("STR") || accept("WORD"))) {
            System.out.println("Parsing error. Factor: syntax error");
        }
}
```

And in the following, regardless of the `else if` clause, you are going to return `false` so you don't even need the second conditional.  And even if you did, the tight loop with a break is just not necessary under any circumstances that I can see.

And no need to declare a static `tokenizer` since your making calls to static methods. Just use the class name `Tokenizer`

So replace the following:

```
private static Tokenizer tokenizer;
    
public static boolean accept(String s) {
    if(tokenizer.tokenList.get(i).equals(s)) {
        i++;
        return true;
    }else if(tokenizer.tokenList.get(i).equals("EOF")) {
        for(;;)
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

with

```
public static boolean accept(String s) {
    if(Tokenizer.tokenList.get(i).equals(s)) {
        i++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And use `equals` not `==` to compare strings (which you do in other places)

```
 @Override
 public String toString() {
     if (token.name() == "SKIP")
         return "";

     return String.format("%-10s: [%s]", token.name(), lexeme);
 }
```

And here in the `Tundra` class

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "float a; a = 3.0; string b; b = \"a\"; extern 
     ~System.out.println(\"e\");~;";
        
        ArrayList<Word> words = tokenizer.lex(input);
        
        for (Word word : words) {
            if(word.token.name() == "ERROR")
                throw new java.lang.Error("Lexing Error: The token \'" + 
    word.lexeme + "\' is invalid");
            
            if(word.token.name() != "SKIP") {
                tokenizer.tokenList.add(String.valueOf(word.token));
                tokenizer.lexemeList.add(String.valueOf(word.lexeme));
            }
        }
        tokenizer.tokenList.add("EOF");
        tokenizer.lexemeList.add("EOF");
        
        System.out.println(tokenizer.tokenList + "\n" + tokenizer.lexemeList);
        parser.program();
    }
```